# Error in appendchild

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following very simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" >

    function showAlert(){
      alert("I am clicked");
    }

    function one(){
      var a1 = [1,2,3];
      for (var i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = a1[i];
        p.onclick = showAlert;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }

      console.log("I am called");
    }

    one();   
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`. Can anybody tell me, where am I going wrong? I am testing in `Chrome`.

Answer (score 4):

`document.body.appendChild` is run before the body is defined, hence `document.body` is still `null`.

Either move this script down under the `<body></body>` or delay it's execution with:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () { /* we're ready */ });
```

Comment: Thanks but me too found the problem and was about to delete the question and saw your answer.

Comment: there's a typo, it's `addEventListener("load", function(){})` or `onload = function(){}`

Answer (score 3):

```
document.body.appendChild(p)
```

In this line. Some days ago I had the same problem.
This happens if you put your script before of the  tag body.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >

    function showAlert(){
                    alert("I am clicked");
                    }


    function one(){
            var a1 = [1,2,3];
                    for (var i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.innerHTML = a1[i];
                    p.onclick = showAlert;
                    document.body.appendChild(p);
                    }

            console.log("I am called");
            }

            one();


     </script>
 </head>
 </html>
```

Will not work.
If you put your function call after the  tag it works.

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script>

    function showAlert(){
                    alert("I am clicked");
                    }


    function one(){
            var a1 = [1,2,3];
                    for (var i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.innerHTML = a1[i];
                    p.onclick = showAlert;
                    document.body.appendChild(p);
                    }

            console.log("I am called");
            }

    </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <body>
<script type="text/javascript" >
            one();
     </script>
 </html>
```

In your context, "body" yet didn't be initialized, so it is null

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the body tag from your HTML.  So document.body is null